# careers@stackoverflow.com rejecting requests

Tags: support, jobs, email

I tried to send an email to careers@stackoverflow.com from my personal mail account; however, it appears my email was rejected, with the following message from GMail:

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

    careers@stackoverfow.com

Technical details of permanent failure:
The recipient server did not accept our requests to connect. Learn more at http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=7720
[allmail.0b2.net. (10): Connection refused]
```

I had a support question that I had preferred not to ask in a public forum such as meta. Is this email address still a valid address to contact for support on careers.stackoverflow.com?

Comment: I just sent a test e-mail from my Yahoo account. We'll see if it gets returned.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're missing a 'l' in the email address you sent your email to.

Comment: Oops. We'll see what kind of witty reply I get. :)

Comment: So, it happens to be the case I'm a moron. :) Thanks for your help.

Comment: @kbrimington you could have waited just 8 hours to ask the question so you would have the backup argument it was a bad april fools joke.